# Can I set the enviroment when running under chef-solo using attributes file?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Chef 11.6 adds environment support for chef-solo as documented here http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_environments.html#set-using-chef-solo

However I can't find a way of setting the environment from the JSON attributes file. I've tried setting `environment` and `chef_environment` keys in the json file, and neither seem to work. I can set the environment via the solo.rb file, but I was wondering if it is possible via the json attributes file too?

I'm invoking like this:

```
chef-solo -l debug -c solo.rb -j node.json
```

solo.rb contains:

```
root = File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

cookbook_path root + '/cookbooks'
data_bag_path root + '/data_bags'
role_path root + '/roles'
environment_path root + '/environments'
verbose_logging :false
```

node.json contains:

```
{
  "run_list": [ "recipe[env_log]" ],
  "environment": "test1",
  "chef_environment": "test2"
}
```

and the env_log recipe has just `Chef::Log.info("Environment #{node.chef_environment}")` in it.

Answer (score 3):

It assumes the environment is specified by the parameter `-E` or `--environment` when running `chef-solo`. for example:

```
chef-solo -l debug -c solo.rb -j node.json -E test2
```

If you didn't specifying this, node.chef_environment will be `_default`.
Refer to the latest code of [chef-solo](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/application/solo.rb#L163)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chef Solo as part of my daily Chef tasks, but I did get this to work a while ago while experimenting.  I created a file **/etc/chef/solo.rb** and in the file put the environment like:

```
environment "YOUR_ENV_NAME"
```

For the environment data, I copied all the my chef repo's environment files to /var/chef/environments on the node

```
cp -r <repo>/environments/* /mnt/to/solo/node/var/chef/environments
```

I had to have Chef 11.6 for this to work.